# How can I remove everything inside of a <div>

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="test">

...
...

</div>
```

I would like to remove all of the elements within the div so I tried:

```
$('#test > div').remove();
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Am I doing the right thing here?

Comment: `$('#test > div')` asks for all `div` elements that are children of the element with id `test`.  Drop the `> div` part, see answer by @Marcel (+1).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try with right syntax

> **[Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove)** : Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
 $('div#test').remove();
```

try with **[empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty)**

> **empty** : Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
 $('#test').empty();
```

see **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)** also, sometime it is helpful

> **html:** When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that
>   was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

***Note:*** To remove the elements without removing data and events, use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach) instead.

Answer (score 3):

`$("#test").empty()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/53ZRw/

this should do it.

```
$('#test').html('');
```

if you want to completly remove you can use

```
.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

should this is works too

```
$('#test > div ').text('');
```