# How to unload the HTML page loaded in div tagafter 5 sec using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have following div in my page with some css.
 with this I have few div on top and below it.**

HTML:

```
  <div id="sentdiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sentdiv{
    margin-left: 13rem;
    margin-right: 20rem;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 50px;

}
```

Then I have a ajax call where in I am loading some html page like below.

JS:

```
$.post('/logme', function(resp) {
    $("#sentdiv").load("success.html");
});
```

here I want to unload the success.html after 5 sec and keep the div with its CSS.

I have tried following

```
$("#sentdiv").delay(5000).replaceWith("<p>");
$("#sentdiv").delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

but It is moving the elements below it. I want to keep div and just remove the contents of div.

Comment: [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: `delay()` is not a replacement for `setTimeout()`, as specifically noted in the API.  `delay()` only affects the timing of animations that jQuery performs using it's internal animation queue.

Comment: Look at [Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14226803/215552) in addition to the doc I posted earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove everything inside of a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000073/how-can-i-remove-everything-inside-of-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery method [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
 $("#sentdiv").empty();
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 $("#sentdiv").empty();
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sentdiv">

<span>this will be removed in five seconds...</span>

</div>
```